# Recursive call until value is not more on response

Tags: php, curl, recursion

I have a cURL call to this `services/data/v28.0/query/?q=SELECT Id,Name,LastModifiedDate FROM Territory` and the response looks like:

```
{
  "totalSize": 6911,
  "done": false,
  "nextRecordsUrl": "/services/data/v28.0/query/01g8000002eI8dMAAS-2000",
  "records": [ ... ]
}
```

That means complete set of records will have 6911 items but on first request just the first 2000 are return, now if I change a bit the cURL call into this `/services/data/v28.0/query/01g8000002eI8dMAAS-2000` I will get the next 2000 items for the first 6911 and so on.

I should call the cURL recursive until `done = true` or `nextRecordsUrl` will be `NULL` or doesn't exists anymore on the response, how? I need some advice or pseudo-code that illustrate me how to achieve this since I am a bit stucked.

This shows the complete set of recursive calls I should perform (this could be dynamic so hard code won't work):

```
call: 
/services/data/v28.0/query/?q=SELECT Id,Name,LastModifiedDate FROM Territory

response:
{
  "totalSize": 6911,
  "done": false,
  "nextRecordsUrl": "/services/data/v28.0/query/01g8000002eI8dMAAS-2000",
  "records": [ ... ]
}

call: 
/services/data/v28.0/query/01g8000002eI8dMAAS-2000

response:
{
  "totalSize": 6911,
  "done": false,
  "nextRecordsUrl": "/services/data/v28.0/query/01g8000002eI8dMAAS-4000",
  "records": [ ... ]
}

call: 
/services/data/v28.0/query/01g8000002eI8dMAAS-4000

response:
{
  "totalSize": 6911,
  "done": false,
  "nextRecordsUrl": "/services/data/v28.0/query/01g8000002eI8dMAAS-6000",
  "records": [ ... ]
}

call: 
/services/data/v28.0/query/01g8000002eI8dMAAS-6000

response:
{
  "totalSize": 6911,
  "done": true,
  "records": [ ... ]
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have figured out, more or less, how to achieve this but now the my problem turns in how to merge recursive the values from each response. See code below:

```
$soqlQuery2 = "SELECT Id,Name,LastModifiedDate FROM Territory";
$soqlUrl2 = $instanceUrl.'/services/data/v28.0/query/?q='.urlencode($soqlQuery2);

$curl = curl_init($soqlUrl2);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: OAuth $veevaToken"));

$jsonResponse = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$soqlObj2 = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);

$this->performPaginateSOQLQuery($veevaToken, $instanceUrl, $tokenUrl, $soqlObj2['nextRecordsUrl']);
```

Above in `$soqlObj2['done']` and `$soqlObj2['nextRecordsUrl']` I will have the values I need for the second and recursive calls. So, I built this function:

```
public function performPaginateSOQLQuery($veevaToken, $instanceUrl, $tokenUrl, $nextRecordsUrl)
{
    if (isset($nextRecordsUrl) && $nextRecordsUrl !== null && $nextRecordsUrl !== "") {
        $nextRecordsUrlSOQLQuery = $instanceUrl.$nextRecordsUrl;

        $curl = curl_init($nextRecordsUrlSOQLQuery);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: OAuth $veevaToken"));

        $jsonResponse = curl_exec($curl);

        $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($status != 200) {
            $respObj['error'] = "Error: call to token URL $tokenUrl failed with status $status, response $jsonResponse, curl_error ".curl_error(
                    $curl
                ).", curl_errno ".curl_errno($curl);

            return $respObj;
        }

        curl_close($curl);

        $nextRecordsUrlObj = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);

        while ($nextRecordsUrlObj['done'] !== true) {
            $this->performPaginateSOQLQuery($veevaToken, $instanceUrl ,$tokenUrl, $nextRecordsUrlObj['nextRecordsUrl']);
        }

        return $nextRecordsUrlObj;
    }
}
```

But I need to merge the whole `$soqlObj2` with `$nextRecordsUrlObj` from each iteration on `performPaginateSOQLQuery()` call, how? Any help?

**UPDATE 2: Losing values on 1st iteration**

I've updated my code to this:

```
public function performPaginateSOQLQuery(
    $veevaToken,
    $instanceUrl,
    $tokenUrl,
    &$nextRecordsUrl,
    &$dataToSave = array()
) {
    if (isset($nextRecordsUrl) && $nextRecordsUrl !== null && $nextRecordsUrl !== "") {
        $nextRecordsUrlSOQLQuery = $instanceUrl.$nextRecordsUrl;

        $curl = curl_init($nextRecordsUrlSOQLQuery);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: OAuth $veevaToken"));

        $jsonResponse = curl_exec($curl);

        $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($status != 200) {
            $respObj['error'] = "Error: call to token URL $tokenUrl failed with status $status, response $jsonResponse, curl_error ".curl_error(
                    $curl
                ).", curl_errno ".curl_errno($curl);

            return $respObj;
        }

        curl_close($curl);

        $nextRecordsUrlObj = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);

        echo $nextRecordsUrlObj['nextRecordsUrl'] . "\n";
        print_r($nextRecordsUrlObj);

        $dataToSave[] = $nextRecordsUrlObj;

        $i = 0;
        while ($nextRecordsUrlObj['done'] !== true) {
            echo "time ".$i;
            $i++;
            $this->performPaginateSOQLQuery(
                $veevaToken,
                $instanceUrl,
                $tokenUrl,
                $nextRecordsUrlObj['nextRecordsUrl'],
                $dataToSave
            );
        }

        return array('url' => $nextRecordsUrlObj, 'data' => $dataToSave);
    }
}
```

But on iteration `time 1` I am getting this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
  Notice: Undefined index: nextRecordsUrl
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop with a boolean variable.
Once the response you get is the last one (`done` property is `true`) change the value of that boolean variable and the loop should stop.

```
<?php

//Assuming $response contains the response you're getting
//and that it's JSON-encoded.

$keepRequesting = true;
while($keepRequesting){

  //Your curl code over here
  // ...

  $response = json_decode($response);
  if($response->done == true) {
     $keepRequesting = false;
  }

}
```

**Regarding your update:**
While I don't think you should use recursive methods for this problem,
just add the data you want to "save" [as a reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) to the function and use `array_merge`. Something like that:

```
public function performPaginateSOQLQuery($veevaToken, $instanceUrl, $tokenUrl, $nextRecordsUrl, &$dataToSave = array()) { //1 new parameters.
    //More code here...


    $nextRecordsUrlObj = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);
    $dataToSave[] = $nextRecordsUrlObj;
    while ($nextRecordsUrlObj['done'] !== true) {
        $this->performPaginateSOQLQuery($veevaToken, $instanceUrl ,$tokenUrl, $nextRecordsUrlObj['nextRecordsUrl'], $dataToSave);
    }

    return array('url' => $nextRecordsUrlObj, 'data' => $dataToSave);
```

The problem is that you should return it, otherwise it will get lost.
You'll have to change the function a bit so it would return the URL and the data you want.

Maybe this post would help you:
[php recursion global variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434693/php-recursion-global-variable)

Comment: Hi, before you answer me I've figured out how to achieve this, I think, but I am running into a second issue, can you take a look to my edit? If you can help me at all I will vote your answer as accepted, thx

Comment: I am not getting your point here, can you change a bit my function - as an example - in order to get what you are talking about?

Comment: Using my edit as main example: `$soqlObj2` will be `$dataToSave` and `$nextRecordsUrlObj` will be `$saved`? I am not getting what those vars should be also

Comment: Edited the code so it would use only one variable, also added the behavior of the function call.

Comment: Two more things, `$saved` on your return statement should be `$dataToSave` right? a typo? When I call the function for first time as `$this->performPaginateSOQLQuery($veevaToken, $instanceUrl, $tokenUrl, $soqlObj2['nextRecordsUrl']);``; `$dataToSave` will be the complete `$soqlObj2` object?

Comment: Yes - that a type. On your first call you should send nothing (just skip that parameter). You can also send an empty array if you're willing.

Comment: Another one, if I am not mistaken `$this->performPaginateSOQLQuery($veevaToken, $instanceUrl ,$tokenUrl, $nextRecordsUrlObj['nextRecordsUrl'], $dataToSave);` should be `$this->performPaginateSOQLQuery($veevaToken, $instanceUrl ,$tokenUrl, $nextRecordsUrlObj['url'], $dataToSave);` on the recursive call since you'd changed the return to send that value on `url` key, I am right?

Comment: Why did you return `array('url' => $nextRecordsUrlObj, 'data' => $dataToSave)`? `while` never stop cause `$nextRecordsUrlObj['done']` is not in the response, why?

Comment: Also take a look to my 2nd edit I am getting another weird issue